# The order of minor in the total graph of a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Does the total graph of a regular finite graph with maximum degree $\Delta$ have a $K_{\Delta+2}$ minor?

I think no. It has a clique of order $\Delta+1$. But, I dont think that deleting a few edges and contracting the vertices could ever produce a clique with an extra vertex. Specifically, since the structure is similar to line graph of the graph, and line graph is not seen to have such a minor, I think even the total graph of a graph does not have a $K_{\Delta+2}$ minor. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Are the graphs required to be finite? If no, then the infinite path is a counterexample: the total graph of a infinite path is outerplanar, so it does not have any $K_4$ minor.

Comment: @LeechLattice yes, edited the question. By the way, did you mean that the total graph of an infinite path has a $K_4$ minor? Otherwise, it would not be a counterexample, rather, an example in the theorems' favour

Comment: No, because the total graph of an infinite graph is outerplanar.

Comment: @LeechLattice the same argument would do for even finite cycles and paths, both of which are planar, I think?

Comment: Yes for paths (but paths are not regular), no for cycles.

Comment: @LeechLattice I think total graphs of cycles are 1-planar, as they consist of three disjoint cycles, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102335/discussion-between-leechlattice-and-vidyarthi).

Comment: I really wish you would try some small examples before posting your conjectures. (Or at least post them on MSE.)
I had never even heard of total graph. I looked it up, and the first example I tried to help me understand was a counter-example. Start with $K_3$, with $\Delta=2$. The total graph of this has six vertices, and is isomorphic to $K_6$ minus a perfect matching. Contract any edge, and you get $K_5$ minus an edge, which contains a $K_4$.

Comment: @verret great! and thanks. Then, is it not a counterexample to Hadwiger' conjecture? Because, the chromatic number of total graph of $K_3$ is $3$. But, since you show that a $K_4$ minor exists, it would be opposing the Hadwiger conjecture.

Comment: @vidyarthi Can you explain why you think this is a counterexample to the Hadwiger Conjecture?

Comment: @verret oh! ok. The Hadwiger conjecture says that if a graph has no $K_k$ minor, then it is $k-$ colorable. But, I thought the converse was also true. Thanks for pointing out the error. But, when can the converse of Hadwiger be true?

Comment: I think it would be a good question if asked in the reverse direction: all total graphs of finite regular graphs I have checked contain a $K_{Δ+2}$ minor.

Comment: @LeechLattice ok. But, do they also have a $K_{\Delta+3}$ minor too?